# Query using column type 'real' returning unexpected values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008 R2, I've got a table with a column called 'Value' that is of type 'real'.
If I do a query like:

```
select * from tableName where Value = 1234567.12
```

the query returns a resultset that has values like `1234567`

Why is it doing this? Should it not only return values that are exactly `1234567.12`?

Comment: Why are you using `REAL` instead of `DECIMAL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `real` data type [is equivalent to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) `float(24)` which only provides about seven decimal digits of precision, and you appear to be using that up all that precision in the non-fractional part of your number.

If you want more precision, you can opt for `float(53)`, or a more specific type like `float(42)`.

In fact, I'd even go so far as to suggest using these floating point values is not such a good idea. There are more *exact* types that you can use, ones that won't introduce you to the pain of limited floating point precision.

Have a look at the "exact numerics" section on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) for some of those types, such as `bigint` for whole numbers, or `decimal/numeric` for real numbers.